# CentOS VM deployed on ESXi 5.5.0 has no IPv4 address

Tags: networking, centos, vmware-esxi

This is what I have tried:

1. I deployed a Centos7 VM on my friend's ESXi 5.5.0 and it works fine.
2. I install the same copy of ESXi on my desktop and migrate my VM to my own newly installed ESXi server. Results in no IPv4 address.
3. I deploy a fresh VM on my server instead of migrating. Results in no IPv4.
4. I migrate the VM deployed in (3) above to my friend's ESXi and it shows an IPv4.
5. I turn of IPv6 address. Results in no IPv4.
6. I tried restarting network service, DHC refresh, ESXi reset. Results in no IPv4.

I matched the settings and parameters on both our ESXi servers - exactly same.

Help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the IP/LAN port that I had connected the machine to was configured to only assign one IP address. Once I put the ethernet cable into another port, it started working fine.